# how to count specific column in a table (select count(product) from stock ) and how to display in jsp using jdbc?

Tags: sql, jdbc

Suppose, we want to get data from table we use PreparedStatement ps

Then suppose, we want to get data from table we use PreparedStatement ps then
ResultSet rs

- `rs.next()`
- `rs.getString()` or `getInt()`

like that, how to get  `select count(product) from stock;`

Comment: What exactly is your question? You apparently already know that you need to run the query using `Statement.executeQuery()` then, use `ResultSet.getInt(1)` to get the value

Answer (score 0):

To read Data from any SQL-Statement using a PreparedStatement you will need something like the following:

```
String sql= "select count(product) from stock";

PreparedStatement ps= dbConnection.prepareStatement(sql);
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

rs.next()

int numberOfProducts = rs.getInt(1):
```

Also don't forget:

```
rs.close();
dbConnection.close();
```